# javaFX scene builder button doesn't work, any solution?

Tags: button, javafx, builder, scene

I've been trying to solve this issue in a very simple application to get button click to work, but everything I tried(by following some tutorials or related answers here) doesn't work. I created a new javaFX project and these are the files created with my editings, 
PS i'm using netbeans

**UserLogin.java**

```
public class UserLogin extends Application {

    @FXML
    Button signup;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLUserSignIn.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();  
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**FXMLUserSignInController**

```
    public void SignUpPush(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent userSignIn = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLUserSignUp.fxml"));
        Scene userSignInSc = new Scene(userSignIn);

        Stage window = (Stage)(((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());

        window.setScene(userSignInSc);
        window.show();

    } 

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    }   
}
```

**FXMLUserSignUpController**

```
public class FXMLUserSignUpController implements Initializable {

    public void BackPush(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Parent userSignIn = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLUserSignIn.fxml"));
        Scene userSignInSc = new Scene(userSignIn);

        Stage window = (Stage)(((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());

        window.setScene(userSignInSc);
        window.show();

    } 
    /**
     * Initializes the controller class.
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }  
}
```

**FXMLUserSignIn**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXPasswordField?>
<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXTextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="301.0" prefWidth="437.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.donation.controllers.FXMLUserSignInController">
   <children>
      <Pane layoutX="19.0" layoutY="14.0" prefHeight="269.0" prefWidth="401.0" style="-fx-background-color: #ffffff;">
         <children>
            <JFXTextField focusColor="#47daf4" labelFloat="true" layoutX="103.0" layoutY="33.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="204.0" promptText="Email" unFocusColor="#b2afaf">
               <font>
                  <Font size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXTextField>
            <JFXPasswordField focusColor="#47daf4" labelFloat="true" layoutX="103.0" layoutY="119.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="204.0" promptText="Password" unFocusColor="#b2afaf">
               <font>
                  <Font size="13.0" />
               </font>
            </JFXPasswordField>
            <JFXButton buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="95.0" layoutY="201.0" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="68.0" ripplerFill="WHITE" style="-fx-background-color: #2196F3;" text="Login" textFill="WHITE" />
            <JFXButton fx:id="handle" buttonType="RAISED" layoutX="223.0" layoutY="201.0" onAction="#SignUpPush" prefHeight="35.0" prefWidth="68.0" ripplerFill="WHITE" style="-fx-background-color: #2196F3;" text="Sign up" textFill="WHITE" />
         </children>
      </Pane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**FXMLUserSignUp**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.jfoenix.controls.JFXButton?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" fx:controller="com.donation.controllers.FXMLUserSignUpController">
   <children>
      <Label layoutX="260.0" layoutY="177.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="102.0" text="hi" />
      <JFXButton layoutX="260.0" layoutY="265.0" onAction="#BackPush" text="Back" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

I'd be very thankful for any kind of help.

Comment: Your question, at least to me, is not clear. You mention a problem with a button. _Which_ button? What _exactly_ is the problem? What should the button be doing in the first place? Are you getting any errors? If so, what are they? Also, the provided code won't compile, and thus isn't an actual [mre]. And what is the  purpose of the `@FXML Button signup` field in your application class? You don't appear to be using the application class as an FXML controller (which is a _Good Thing_), so that field will never be injected by an `FXMLLoader`.

Comment: uhh yeah that declaration is nothing i was just testing some stuff, in fact the button with fx:id='handle' should execute the SignUpPush function which i suppose should transfer me to the other fxml page but it didn't.

Comment: As I run the program and then click the button this error appears:
https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/36ac

Comment: Note it's best to include code and errors in the question itself—[as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6395627). You can [edit] your question to add more information. That said, the problem is `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.` That means you're setting the location of the `FXMLLoader` to `null` because `getClass().getResource(...)` is returning `null`, which in turn means the resource could not be found. Make sure you're using the correct resource name.

Comment: Well i actually figured it out the whole problem was that jdk version wasn't 1.8 it's not a code prolem xD